# Disable DIV in ionic 4 with angular material

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular-material, ionic4

I am working in ionic 4 application which built by angular material HTML tag. My case is, I need to disable the specific DIV using DOM If the certain criteria meets in the entry page. The specific DIV may have any no.of children(components) such as input, mat-select, mat-radio-group. I tried several ways to achieve this. Each solution has some drawbacks. For example, the below solution I tried.

`document.getElementById(divID).style['pointer-events'] = 'none';`

The above code disabled all the children properly. But It allow the keyboard tab keys to shift between the fields and able to enter the input. It restricts only the mouse pointer interaction.

Kindly suggest or provide solution for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**disable the child elements of a div**

```
const children = document.getElementById(divID).children;
for(var i = 0; i< children.length; i++){
    children[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: How I need to use this programmatically using DOM ?

Comment: No luck. Still I am able to access the fields and giving inputs using tab key.

Comment: you also need to get the child items and disable them too

Comment: document.getElementById(sectionName).style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
document.getElementById(sectionName).setAttribute("tabindex","-1");

I tried like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221823/discussion-between-sundaramoorthy-j-and-firatozcevahir).